# Is it a good idea to leave an explanatory comment after flagging a question for migration to another SE site?

Tags: discussion, comment, migration, etiquette

If I flag a question because I think it's more about programming than about statistics, does it make sense to leave a comment explaining why I think so? I usually don't do that (I don't flag and then comment), because I don't want to induce the OP to close his/her question and ask a new one on SO. Instead, flagging and then letting moderators decide if to move the question to SO is better, because then there's a record of the question having already been asked to CV. This prevents objectively annoying situations where the OP moves the question to SO, only to be (kindly or not) suggested to move it to CV. However, if the OP is completely new to StackExchange, I thought that leaving an explanatory comment, together with flagging the post, may make him/her feel more welcome and less disoriented, in case the post does get moved to SO. What do you think? The specific case is

[I want to compare two datasets to determine which variables they share](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276198/i-want-to-compare-two-datasets-to-determine-which-variables-they-share)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this possibility? You could leave a comment about the scope of topics on this site, mention your suggested destination and then *suggest that the OP flag it to migrate rather than repost* (whether you also flag it yourself is up to you) .

However, it's a good idea before suggesting a post belongs on another SE site to make sure it fits with the on-topic page for that site (for example, if it's a post about an error message, it's actually off-topic on SO unless the post satisfies several conditions). Once you're familiar with the requirements for the destination site, you don't need to keep re-checking, but many flags to migrate don't go through because the post actually doesn't meet the requirements of the destination. (Sometimes the post can be edited to meet the requirements and then migrate.)